# What CAP-Type does LevelDB(RocksDB) have?

Tags: distributed, leveldb, cap-theorem, rocksdb

During the evaluation of several distributed systems I came across the CAP-Theorem. Unfortunately I can't find a classification for LevelDB or to be more specific RocksDB.

Here is the actual question: What kind of cap-type is LevelDB/RocksDB and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LevelDB and RocksDB are not distributed databases. Hence, Brewer's CAP Theorem is inapplicable.

Comment: Ah thanks. I thought sharding is possible. Further investigation show that sharding has to be implemented on application side...

Comment: Anyway... if it isn't a distributed system (not necessarily database) it would be a CA-type if i got Brewer right.

Comment: The "A" and "P" parts of CAP aren't applicable to non-distributed systems at all. It is inaccurate to say a non-distributed system is "CA-type."